# Issue On checkout Page after enabling Austrian Dollor Currency

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout

I have enabled currency for Australian dollar from admin section

[image]

After enabling this I am getting below error.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Undefined rate from "AUD-USD".

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Undefined rate from "AUD-USD".
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/ShippingMethodConverter.php(61): Magento\Directory\Model\Currency->convert(10, 'USD')
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php(140): Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter->modelToDataObject(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate), 'USD')
```

Please suggest what is the way to enable currency for different country.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue with currency rates, whenever you add new currency to store it require import/add currency rates, You can add it by

```
Admin >> Store >> Currency >> Currency Rates
```

Comment: Yes,I did it but still issue is appearing.Have you any idea?

Comment: Check again it after flush cache/reindexing, privet browser window.

Comment: Still not Working after reindexing as well as compile and upgrade.

Comment: Please add USD as base and default currency.

Comment: I have already this as per shared above screen-shot.

Comment: As per screen shot it's wrong. Please change value ausralian dollar to US dollar in Base and Default currency. And also set Allowed Currencies with US dollar and  Ausralian dollar.